# Submitting an explicitly NULL parameter via httr

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, httr

Is there a way to submit `NULL` as a JSON parameter via `httr`?

When I do `httr::POST("https://httpbin.org/post", body = list(a = 1, b = NULL), httr::verbose(), encode = "json”)`, I see in the output that `b = NULL` gets dropped from the payload somewhere, even though `list(a = 1, b = NULL)` is a valid R list that has an existent `b` value set to `NULL`.

In Python's `requests` library, submitting a `None` parameter is permitted and I'm using an API that depends on that behavior (maybe not the smartest design choice, but it's what I have to live with). Is there any way for `httr` or `RCurl` or something to interface with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is caused by `body <- compact(body)` in `httr:::body_config`. You could workaround by not providing the body as a `list`, but as `character` with the json directly.

Not sure if the below returns exactly what you expect, but you could send the body directly as a character vector containing the `json`:

```
httr::POST(
  "https://httpbin.org/post",
  body = '{"a":1,"b":"None"}',
  httr::verbose(),
  encode = "json"
)
```

Or, "programatically":

```
httr::POST(
  "https://httpbin.org/post",
  body = jsonlite::toJSON(list(a = 1, b = "None"), auto_unbox = TRUE),
  httr::verbose(),
  encode = "json"
)
```

From `httr:POST`'s help on the body parameter: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.0/topics/POST

Note that with `jsonlite::toJSON` there are a few options to choose from, depending on what you actually want to `POST` as the body:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(list(a = 1, b = NA), auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"a":1,"b":null} 

jsonlite::toJSON(list(a = 1, b = NULL), auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"a":1,"b":{}} 

jsonlite::toJSON(list(a = 1, b = NA_integer_), auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"a":1,"b":"NA"}

jsonlite::toJSON(list(a = 1, b = list()), auto_unbox = TRUE)
# {"a":1,"b":[]}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is also similar to the answer I got on https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/561